# MapTiler warped overlay fix?

Tags: geospatial, maptiler

I want to use MapTiler to create a custom overlay onto OpenStreetMaps but I keep getting extremely warped output from MapTiler and I don't know why. The output from each attempt is different although I use the same starting image and the same control points (8 in total) for georeferencing.

For each attempt I make I follow the steps outlined in the MapTiler tutorial video for custom overlays (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=by5sTBs1qOA).

Below are 4 examples of the warped overlay output. Does anyone have any recommendations of how to fix this problem?

[image: Warped MapTiler custom overlay 1]

[image: Warped MapTiler custom overlay 2]

[image: Warped MapTiler custom overlay 3]

[image: Warped MapTiler custom overlay 4]

Answer (score 0):

Your control points are very probably not correct. Be sure the pair of places on which you click are exactly the same.

The whole process is demonstrated in the video you linked - follow it exactly!

You may also try to use only 3 points - when precisely placed they provide enough information for correct overlay of a detailed map as you have on the image.

MapTiler 0.6.1+ also allows selection of the transformation method (in the options dialog) to control what deformation is applied to the image.

Still, in your case, there is very probably a collision on the points you provided - which is causing the visual issue.